# Transition div position from bottom to top of container

Tags: css, css-position, css-transitions

I'm trying to get an (absolutely positioned) div to transition from bottom: 0 to top: 0 of it's parent div. I can happily get it to transition from bottom: 0 to bottom: 10rem for example, but not to top: 0. Any ideas anyone? Please see the code example below and thanks in advance!

```css
        .container {
            position: relative;
            height: 20rem;
            width: 20rem;
            border: solid blue 0.05rem;
        }

        .child {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5rem;
            width: 5rem;
            background-color: red;
            bottom: 0;
            top: auto;
            transition: all 1s;
        }

        .child:hover {
            top: 0;
            bottom: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: One thing to point out, missing in the current answers: You can only transition from one _value_ to another. You cannot transition from the value of one _property_ to the value of another _property_. Meaning you can't transition from `bottom: 0` to `top: 0`. Instead you have to transition from one `top` value to another as in [@Gildas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58247807/2311559)

Answer (score 3):

Use the The [calc() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), then `:hover` the parent not the `child`.

```css
 .container {
            position: relative;
            height: 20rem;
            width: 20rem;
            border: solid blue 0.05rem;
        }

        .child {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5rem;
            width: 5rem;
            background-color: red;
            top: calc( 100% - 5rem ); /*100% - height*/
            transition: all .3s ease;
            will-change: top;
        }

  .container:hover  .child{
            top: 0;  
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You can also use [The transform CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) to translate the child element.

```css
 .container {
            position: relative;
            height: 20rem;
            width: 20rem;
            border: solid blue 0.05rem;
        }

        .child {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 5rem;
            width: 5rem;
            background-color: red;
            bottom: 0;
            transition: all .3s ease;
            will-change: bottom;
        }

.container:hover  .child{
    bottom: 100%;
    transform: translateY(100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```